# Change textview everyday automatically

Tags: android, textview

First I want to change textview text everyday automatically. For example, first day the textview text is "First text", and second day text is "Second text" at 8 o'clock eveyday. And the text is permanent until next day 8 o'clock.

I try this code but my problem is that the code is not triggered if the user doesn't open this page at 8 o'clock. Texts are inside "mquote array"

```
 SharedPreferences pref =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ; 
    dayCount = pref.getInt("dayCount", 0);


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);        


    if ((hour==8 && minute==1 ))
        updateQuote();


tvQuote.setText(mquote.getQuote(dayCount));

public void updateQuote()
{

        if (dayCount==4)
            dayCount=0;
    dayCount++;
    pref.edit().putInt("dayCount",dayCount).apply();


}
```

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Instead of checking for exact time (8:01), check if it's greater than a certain value.

Comment: This does not work because you are checking that the time is 8:01. You should check if the time is greater 8:00 and if you are still on the same day.

Comment: @zed it is good but each click changes text on the same day. So new problem is how to know day is same or not

Answer (score 1):

You need an `AlarmManager` implementation:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // set the Alarm's trigger time to 8:00 a.m.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAT, 9);

        // Set the alarm to fire at approximately 8:30 a.m., according to the device's
        // clock, and to repeat once a day.
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,  
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        } else if(Objects.equals(intent, alarmIntent)) {
            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int dayCount = pref.getInt("dayCount", 0);
            dayCount %= 4;
            pref.edit().putInt("dayCount", ++daysCount).apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store milliseconds when you last updated preferences in your preferences:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("msKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
msCount = pref.getInt("msCount", 0);

long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();

long diff = milliseconds - msCount;

diff += (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // compensating difference for 8'O clock condition

int days = (int) Math.ceil(diff / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000);

days %= 4; // Because you were resetting days count after 4 increments

updateQuote(days);

public void updateQuote(days) {

    if(days == 0) {
        pref.edit().putInt("msCount", milliseconds).apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think it is good algorithm but it doesn't work. When the time is 8 o'clock, text is not updated always first text is there.

Comment: Sounds silly, but, I have not put `tvQuote.setText(mquote.getQuote(dayCount));` in my answer, did you miss it? Also, I am passing `days` to `updateQuote` method.

Comment: I updated textview in terms of days in updateQuote method `tvQuote.setText(mquote.getQuote(days));` Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, we need to perform calculating days every time view is created. Or is being seen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use timestamp to be able to compare two dates. try this code.
But the 1 day happens while user is using the app, it will not trigger. If you want to overcome this, then use AlarmManager to trigger an event every single day.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

lastDay_ms= pref.getInt("time_ms", 0);
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - lastDay_ms; //result in millis

final long ONE_DAY = 24*60*60*1000; //millis in a day

if (diff > ONE_DAY)
     updateQuote();
```

Comment: I think AlarmManager is suitable. You advise AlarmManager first. Thank you for answering. @uguboz